String searching in Google Gemini Advanced
With Google Gemini Advanced, I am using a google sheet to answer questions about the content in the sheet rows. Some of the rows/records contain multiple values. Ex. (corn, pastures, hay, black beans) I want to find only those rows/records that contain the word corn. However Gemini will only return results if the entire list of values (corn, pastures, hay, black beans) is explicitly searched. Gemini will only return results if the entire list of values (corn, pastures, hay, black beans) is explicitly searched.
I want to find only those rows/records that contain the word corn. However Gemini will only return results if the entire list of values (corn, pastures, hay, black beans) is explicitly searched. Gemini will only return results if the entire list of values (corn, pastures, hay, black beans) is explicitly searched.

This question doesn't look to be a specific problem unique to programming. It might belong to [webapps.se] or to [genai.se].
